# Un Autre vs Autre

Tags: adjectifs

Je ne sais pas quelle est la différence entre "un autre" et "autre", dans quels cas on doit utiliser "autre" et dans quels cas on doit écrire "un autre" pour indiquer qu'il y a une chose différente de celle dont on vient de parler.

Answer (score 2):

Le plus souvent, on utilise ***autre chose*** sans article.

> SPIEGEL : *Votre confrère écrivain et actuel ministre André Malraux se compte pourtant parmi ces Français, ces intellectuels de gauche dont nous parlons.*
> Françoise Sagan : Oui, mais c’est autre chose. Malraux est Malraux, ce qui est certainement digne d’éloges, mais il ne bouge pas.
>
> *Le droit à l'insoumission, le dossier des 121*, François Maspero, 1960

La présence de l'article indéfini n'est pas incorrecte et se rencontre parfois sans impact notable sur le sens.

L'article défini est requis si *chose* est défini:

> Je parlais d'autre chose. (indéfini, on ne sait pas de quoi il s'agit)

> Je parlais d'une autre chose. (indéfini, on sait qu'il s'agit d'une unique chose)

> Je parlais de l'autre chose. (défini, on sait de quoi il s'agit)

L'article est habituel si *autre chose* est mis en opposition avec *une chose* :

> C'est une chose ou une autre chose.

mais absent si c'est avec *quelque chose* :

> C'est quelque chose ou autre chose.